# High CPU Usage by IIS even after I stop all the websites

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, performance, iis

I have an Asp.Net MVC 5.1 website on a VPS and until a few days ago everything went perfectly without any problems. It has 4 GB of RAM, quad core CPU (3 GHz) and a SSD for Windows drive (currently 10 GB free space) so I don't think it's a hardware issue.
The problem started after I installed the *Wordpress* using the Web Platform Installer but that might be just a coincidence.
When I restart the VPS everything is smooth. After couple of hours the CPU usage of `w3wp.exe` goes to 100% and never comes down. I stopped all the websites running and waited for a few minutes and it's still at 100% so I'm sure it's not any of the websites. Is there any way for me to troubleshoot where the problem is coming from? Can you guess where I should start?

#### Update:

I restarted the `DefaultApplicationPool` in the server which was related to one of the websites running on the server and it immediately dropped the CPU usage of the IIS to 3. I started it again and it's now going on 3% CPU and the website is fully functional. I think it'll go to 100% soon though!

Comment: Have you seen this [guide](http://www.iis.net/learn/troubleshoot/performance-issues/troubleshooting-high-cpu-in-an-iis-7x-application-pool)?

Comment: Does TaskMan say that IIS (w3wp.exe) is still using all that CPU? Make sure you are chasing the right process.

Comment: @Andrei I haven't seen it but I'm doing the steps mentioned in that article step-by-step. Hopefully it'll help me find the problem.

Comment: @tgolisch Yes, Task Manager is saying that `w3wp.exe` is using the 100% CPU all the time :(

Comment: @tgolisch I did all the tasks given in the given tutorial. Unfortunately none of it helped. The perfmon stuff pointed me to the things I already knew (which process was causing the problem) and the memory dump didn't show me anything useful. It didn't show me any warning or anything else. Please see the update.

Comment: Have you tried checking iis logs to see where the requests are going. You should be able to enable time taken in the logs to see if any are running more than normal and/or more requests are coming in than normal

Comment: I'm reading the logs now and not seeing anything out of the ordinary. Also, I check the Google Analytics, not anything out of the ordinary there. In addition to these, our site has a very lightweight tracking system, I don't see many requests there either. I get the usual page visits.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I followed up the [tutorial](http://www.iis.net/learn/troubleshoot/performance-issues/troubleshooting-high-cpu-in-an-iis-7x-application-pool) mentioned by @[Andrei](https://stackoverflow.com/users/728795/andrei) and confirmed that it's IIS that's taking the high CPU and it's the main site that's taking the CPU. I confirmed this by creating a new application pool and changing the website's pool to that. After a while the CPU usage went to 100% again and I was sure something was wrong with my website.

Then, after some research I came across [this IIS forum thread](http://forums.iis.net/t/1167179.aspx) which gave me some ideas. I used the following command:

`%windir%\system32\inetsrv\appcmd list requests`

And saw that there are a lot of requests hanged at one action. This action was waiting on a web service which returned a list of SMS messages received by our website and wasn't working at the time. I changed the code and disabled it for now. The IIS is currently using 3% CPU.

Comment: Good info.. I knew we could see the current requests via the IIS Console .. but didn't realize this can be done via appcmd as well